# How to find schema of a table in DB2?

Tags: db2, database-administration

I am new to DB2 and I created two tables 'PROJECT_ADAPTERS' and 'PROJECT_APPLICATIONS' under database 'WLADMIN'

I am able to see the tables using 'syscat.tables' as shown below

```
[db2inst1@574 ~]$ db2 "select TABNAME from syscat.tables" | grep PROJ
PROJECT_ADAPTERS                                                           
PROJECT_APPLICATIONS
```

However I am not sure, to which schema it belongs to ?

I tried writing a little script which loops through all the 'schemas'

```
schemaname=$(db2 -v select schemaname from syscat.schemata)

for each_schema in $schemaname
do
    db2 list tables for schema $each_schema | grep PROJ
done
```

However, my tables 'PROJECT_ADAPTERS' and 'PROJECT_APPLICATIONS' are not showing up against any schema

What am I doing wrong (or) where else should I look out for ?

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most tables have multiple columns, you can use them... ;)

`select tabname,tabschema from syscat.tables where tabname like 'PROJECT%'` should show your tables and the schema name.

The catalog [SYSCAT.TABLES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html) is fully documented.

Comment: db2 "select tabname,tabschema from syscat.tables where tabname like 'PROJECT%'" yields me 'PROJECT_ADAPTERS' schema as 'cls'.  But, when I type in "db2 select * from cls.PROJECT_LOCK" it says ""CLS.PROJECT_LOCK" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

Comment: What is the schema reported for PROJECT_LOCK? Is it defined at all? You only said that you could see an entry for PROJECT_ADAPTERS.

Comment: Both the tables PROJECT_ADAPTERS and PROJECT_LOCK belongs to schema 'CLS'.   But, I did not get 'defined' for schema.  Please let me know how to check whether the schema was defined and in case if it was not defined how to define a schema?

Comment: @SathishKumar If the query returns the schema name as "cls" and not "CLS" (case matters), then you must surround the schema name in double quotes, as in `select * from "cls".project_lock`.  This will create challenges when trying to query from the command line, where you have to deal with the shell interpreting the quotes.  Example:  `db2 "select * from \"cls\".project_lock"`

Comment: @Ian  The syntax which you provided worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot